# SQL: error when using function Max () over (order by)

Tags: sql, partition

I have data like this:

```
Valuedate   cusID              late
-----------------------------------
20130822    000083-AC-KH-00063  1
20130823    000083-AC-KH-00063  0
20130824    000083-AC-KH-00063  1
20130825    000083-AC-KH-00063  2
20130826    000083-AC-KH-00063  1
20131020    000170-AC-KH-00031  1
20131021    000170-AC-KH-00031  2
20131022    000170-AC-KH-00031  3
20131023    000170-AC-KH-00031  1
```

And I need to track max late payment of each customer until current value date, so the result must look like:

```
Valuedate   cusID              late max_late
--------------------------------------------
20130822    000083-AC-KH-00063  1   1
20130823    000083-AC-KH-00063  0   1
20130824    000083-AC-KH-00063  1   1
20130825    000083-AC-KH-00063  2   2
20130826    000083-AC-KH-00063  1   2
20131020    000170-AC-KH-00031  1   1
20131021    000170-AC-KH-00031  2   2
20131022    000170-AC-KH-00031  3   3
20131023    000170-AC-KH-00031  1   3
```

I use the following SQL query:

```
select 
    valuedate, cusID, late, 
    max(late) over (partition by cusID order by valuedate) as max_late
from 
    cus_late
order by 
    valuedate, cusID
```

but it always throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'

which I cannot understand why

PS: this code getting universal late date is running well on my data:

```
select  
    valuedate, cusID, late, 
    max(late) over (partition by cusID ) as max_late
from 
    cus_late
order by 
    valuedate, cusID
```

Comment: Your initial query works just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/45c34/1

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, ... ?

Comment: The order of records is irrelevant if you are finding the maximum. This is probably why the RDBMS you are using prevents the order by.